# React SRC code wont show on github pages repo

Tags: reactjs, git, github, github-pages

I used the steps here: https://faizanm0389.github.io/DD-APP/ and sucessfully published a react app. However the github repo on my account that it is associated with does not show any of my src file incluses components and index.js file. I only see my root html and css file but none of my components.

For more context here is the repo: https://github.com/Faizanm0389/DD-APP
and here is my published app: https://faizanm0389.github.io/DD-APP/

I don't know if I should try just manually uploading my react compoents or not

I would like others to be able to see my react code since it is a school/internship project.

Comment: From your github repo page it doesn't seem like you've added your source files to your .gitignore, and there also aren't any additional files in your gh-pages deployment. What does your dev environment look like? Are you building locally and pushing to github or coding on github directly?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @G1N I have my files on my computer that I'm trying to upload on gh pages. The app is on and working fine but my repo doesnt show any my my react files. I have all my .jsx files in src/components

Comment: Are you familiar with using git to commit and push your changes to your github repository?